# Array problem in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am very confused. In the while loop I am adding each file name into an array and printing it afterwards.

However in the for loop it prints some weird things and stops executing in the middle.

Please help me to fix it.

```
char *commands[1000];

char *str;
DIR * dir;

struct dirent * entry;

char *env = getenv("PATH");

do {
    str = strsep(&env, ":");

    if(str != NULL)
        if(strlen(newEnv) > 0) {

            dir = opendir(str);
            if( dir == NULL ) break;

            flag = 0;
            while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                commands[++count] = entry->d_name;
                printf("---%i %s\n", count ,commands[count]);  // prints fine
            }
            closedir(dir); // close directory

        }

} while(newEnv);

commands[++count] = '\0';
printf("count = : %i\n", count);

for(int i = 0; i <  count; i ++)
{
    if(commands[i] == NULL)
        break;
    printf("aaa%i %s\n\n", i, commands[i]);  //problem loop
}
```

Comment: Please try to construct a *minimal* test case (see http://sscce.org/).  All the stuff to do with `opendir`, etc. is probably irrelevant to the problem, so you can probably remove it from your code snippet.

Comment: Note that it is not safe to use `strsep` on environment variables, since it modifies them.  However this is not the source of your problems.

Comment: a properly indented source code helps a lot... what is this `newEnv`variable ?

Comment: Why are you skipping the first array element?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as `newEnv`, `flag`, and `count` are not defined. `strsep()`is not found either but this is maybe because I did not include the proper include file. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your pointers pointing into the `dir` struct received by `readdir`. However, that struct is [deallocated by `closedir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir).

You need to copy the strings (`strdup` and friends).

Comment: Replace `commands[++count] = entry->d_name;` by `commands[++count] = strdup(entry->d_name);`.

Comment: ok that seems working fine but for loop is not executed for some reason??

Comment: I guess, this is because you never set commands[0]. So it might well be 0 and cause your loop to break immediately. You should consider incrementing count *after* you have written to the array, remove that (then) useless line "`commands[++count] = '\0';`" and take care for what MatthieuW pointed out.

Comment: I mean, replace `commands[++count] = entry->d_name; printf("---%i %s\n", count ,commands[count]);` by `commands[count++] = entry->d_name; printf("---%i %s\n", count,commands[count-1]);` (assuming you will remove the printf later).

Answer (score 2):

`commands[++count] = entry->d_name` doesn't copy the `entry->d_name` string into `commands[++count]`, but merely assigns the pointer. In the next iteration `entry->d_name` is overwritten since `readdir` uses static memory for returning the result.

Use `strcpy` instead and allocate the memory yourself.

Comment: is it sth like this???  char *new;  new = strcpy(new, entry->d_name); 
                                                
                                                commands[++count] = new;

Comment: @kanoz: Before the `strcpy` you need to allocate memory like this: `new = malloc(strlen(entry->d_name) + 1)`.

Comment: did that but for loop is not executed this time... why do u think??

Answer (score 0):

The problems:

- you add pointers to the array, which point to strings that will be deallocated by `readdir/closedir` shortly after
- if the starting value of `count` is 0, `commands[0]` is never assigned to and contains garbage
- the `commands[++count] = '\0';` line seems to be a mistake, but luckily it adds 1 to `count` so the `print count` line prints right number and the `for` loop iterates over the right range

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Eugene Homyakov's answer:

You should not rely in your last loop on "commands" array to be initialized with NULL values.

Comment: The order in which answers are displayed on SO is variable - you should probably make this a comment to the relevant answer otherwise it's not clear which answer you are referring to

Comment: Tanks for the tip. Actually I was referring to Eugene comment. My remark is not related but I just prefer not to repeat his useful comments.